# javafx scene builder 2 is not launching

Tags: java, javafx, builder, scene

I was using javafx scene builder just fine few weeks ago. but from yesterday it wont even launch. No error message or anything. just wont work. I tried reinstalling, removing recently installed applications (such as daemon tools etc). Still no luck. Can anyone help me? I'm using windows 7 64 bit OS.

Thanks

Comment: Hey all, Finally i was able to get the scene builder running. In my case it was the bitdefender antivirus. For some reason it blocks java fx scene builder process tagging it as a potentially malicious process. Once i add an exception for the javafx scene builder.exe it started to work. Anyway, i hope this will help someone.