# JavaFX SceneBuilder 8.0.0. failed to launch JVM

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have installed the JavaFx Scene Builder ver. 8.0.0. and it does not start. 
I am getting 2 errors one by another:
1: `Error invoking method: SceneBuilder.exe`
2. `Failed To launch JVM: SceneBuilder.exe`

I have the newest java jdk installed and set to the path. I alsp checked that question [Scene Builder 2.0 not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285698/scene-builder-2-0-not-launching) and changed the values in the registry but the problem is not solved. 
The "standard" version of SceneBuilder (2.0 - from Oracle(?)) works - I am getting the errors by launching the Gluon version.

Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Could you try to run directly the jar `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\app\dist.jar`? This should work with the JDK installed on your system, while the exe should work with the one bundled with the installer, under `runtime` folder.

Comment: Well it turned out as I had used the scenebuilder before I imported some Jars, and that was the Problem. I removed the jar from the Scene builder Roaming directory and could run the scene builder 8.0.0

Comment: I solved that problem. See details link below; [Solution Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134929/gluon-scene-builder-failure-with-netbeans/46242663#46242663)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\com\oracle\javafx\scenebuilder\/J/V/M/User/Options in regedit`
Change the value for **-/Xmx from 999m to 512m**

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to add this line "***app.classpath=.;dist.jar***"
in the *"../app/SceneBuilder.cfg"* file.

It works fine for me.