# Gluon Scene Builder Failure with Netbeans

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm using Gluon Scene Builder but it fails when i want to run any fxml files on Netbeans 8.2. It says like "Failed to launch JVM". I tried all stackoverflow replies but it didnt help my problem. Please help!!!

[image: First Error]

[image: Second Error]

Comment: What OS are you running? Do you have Gluon Scene Builder installed as a standard app or you are using the executable jar version? Are you able to start Scene Builder on its own? Answers to this questions would really help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 x64 and i installed Gluon Scene Builder x64 Version, not jar. I can start Gluon Scene Builder standalone but it didnt run on Netbeans. I can send some screenshots soon if you need. And thank you for your attention.

Comment: Try to describe what are you trying to achieve: do you have a JavaFX app with an FXML file? You can open that file with Scene Builder, but when running the app, you get that error? If this is the case, post the relevant code and stacktrace so we can have a look.

Comment: 1st Error Screenshot is : [1st Error](http://i64.tinypic.com/11gsfnr.png) and 2nd Error Screenshot is : [2nd Error](http://i67.tinypic.com/v445lk.png)

Comment: I see that you are using custom controls. Have you added them to Scene Builder before opening the file? Also if you open Scene Builder first (not from NetBeans), does it open? Can you open any FXML file? Can you open this FXML file? Can you open Scene Builder from command line (go to its installation folder, find `dist.jar` and double click on it)? Check any error you may find on the console.

Comment: I can open that fxml file with only gluon scene builder and also i added custom controls to netbeans and scene builder too like jfoenix.jar etc. I tried to open dist.jar from cmd and it runs perfect. Scene builder is opens all fxml file without netbeans. The problem is that the scene builder doesnt work on netbeans. @JoséPereda

Comment: When you say "only gluon scene builder", do you have other Scene Builder apps installed? What path to Scene Builder do you set on NetBeans?

Comment: I mean "only gluon scene builder" that i tried to open fxml files on it and it runs perfectly. But it gave error with netbeans tohether. I installed as admin rights into Administrator user folder. Actually i tried many things to install. Installed as normal way but it didnt work. Installed as admin and same error. Installed on different folder and/or drive, same. Uninstalled netbeans and then reinstall it but still same. At last i think i will format my pc and try again. I hope it will work :(

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this issue. I didn't format yet. Could you find any solution? @JoséPereda

Comment: Did you set the path to SceneBuilder in NetBeans/Options/JavaFX? Have you tried simple FXML files? Just create a new JavaFX with FXML application, and see if you can open the FXML file on SceneBuilder from NetBeans.

Comment: I set path as "C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder" because i tried to install another path that maybe it works but it didnt. Also netbeans couldn't apply path. I created a simple fxml in netbeans and then i tried to open it but it could't open and gave an error like screenshots. If i run Scene Builder without Netbeans and creates a new fxml, it works fine. But it doesn't work integrated with Netbeans.

Comment: When you say NetBeans couldn't apply path you mean the path remains empty? Then it won't be possible to make it work. Go to NetBeans->Tools->Options->Java->JavaFX, and see what your `Scene Builder Home` combobox shows?

Comment: When i set the path you know that "Apply" button enables. I click "Apply" button but it isnt disable again. So maybe netbeans doesnt accept my path i think.

https://pasteboard.co/GKu3Dx9.png

Comment: That looks fine to me. Let's try something different: Can you set in your PC the language settings to English?

Comment: I recorded a video for you. You can watch on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-bwF88FiI0

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems a NetBeans bug to me. I have a possible issue in mind. For proving it, you'll need to install the English language in your PC, and set it as preferred language. Then try it again as is. Can you do it?

Comment: I have another PC with Turkish language and Netbeans works fine with Gluon. So its not about system language. I will send a video on Monday from other PC. Because its in my office. So im home now.

Comment: I know Turkish language should work fine... but there is a use case precisely with your language when using `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()`  (see [this](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/java-lowercase-conversion-turkey/)). It's a long shot, but maybe when NetBeans tries to open SceneBuilder, the path to it gets affected by that issue. Changing to English, it will use a different Locale, and if that is the case, it should work...

Comment: I solved this problem and solution answer below. So the problem isn't about different Locale. Thanks to me :D

Comment: Glad that you solved it! Out of curiosity, can you check what do you have here: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\javafx2`? I see my paths with blanks, like: `selectedHome=C:\\Program Files\\SceneBuilder#8.3.0-RC3`.

Comment: Checked it!!! its look like *saveBeforeLaunch=false
selectedHome=C:/Users/JavaEngineer/AppData\\Local\\SceneBuilder#8.3.0
userDefinedHomes=*

Comment: I'm not sure yet why the spaces in your user name were a problem (unless for some reason instead of `C:/Users/Java Engineer/...` it used `C:/Users/Java~1/...`. Anyway, if you feel like having a look, [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans/tree/master/javafx2.scenebuilder/src/org/netbeans/modules/javafx2/scenebuilder) you have the NetBeans source code for the load of SceneBuilder.

Comment: I'm not sure too but it works. Weird right? Also im looking that codes that you sent on github. Thanks for your patience. See you another problem.

Comment: Sure. And if you still have the old user "Java Engineer" folders, could you check if you still have the config file `scenebuilder.properties`?

Comment: I still have "Java Engineer" folder but there is just has derby.propertiies file. "scene.properties" file is under new "JavaEngineer" folder

Comment: @JoséPereda could you help this problem too? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447364/gluon-scene-builder-8-4-0-launch-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it at last. The problem is the system user's name. It has some blank like "***Java Engineer***". I uninstalled scene builder from "***Program Files***" folder and renamed default system user as "***JavaEngineer***" then installed again to default path into "***AppData/Local/Scenebuilder***" folder. At last i fixed right path to Netbeans as "***C:\Users\JavaEngineer\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder***". It works fine!!! So i can advice for this problem, users have to change their default user name. Thanks!!!

For solution you can check this video : [Solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_51feM85e8)

Answer (score 0):

If you install Scene Builder in your C: drive, you problem may be solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just edited your post to match the generally professional look of questions and answers on this website. It is generally a bad idea to add silly remarks like "this really works!!!" — it just seems pointlessly giggly, and if it _does_ work, the answer will speak for itself when it is (hopefully) upvoted and/or accepted.