# Gluon Scene Builder 8.4.0 Launch Fails

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I was using Gluon Scene Builder 8.3.0 and i uninstalled it then after i installed new version of 8.4.0 but it gave me some errors when i want to run the program. Errors and java version properties below;

[image: dist.jar Error]

[image: SceneBuilder.exe Error - 1]

[image: SceneBuilder.exe Error - 2]

[image: Java & Javac Version]

Also i tried to open JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0 and its running well. Screenshot below;

[image: Java & Javac Version]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, but now I'm convinced it has to do with your locale settings

Comment: Can you do a quick test? Just change your locale settings in your PC to English, and try again?

Comment: Problem solved. Interesting because of  that about locale language. Weird. And also many thanks for your helps

Comment: I've now reproduced your issue within the source code, setting a Turkish locale in the app: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("tr", "TR"));`. So I've filed an issue in the SceneBuilder [repo](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/146/npe-with-turkish-locale).

Comment: Thanks too much for your attention, again!!! @JoséPereda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 1st thanks to Jose Pereda for help me to solve this problem. You have to change your locale language to English as this link below if your locale is Turkish language. But don't worry, the gluon team will fix this issue soon.

[Locale Language Settings for Windows](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml)

Comment: To be clear, your answer is correct in case you have Turkish locale settings, and while this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/146/npe-with-turkish-locale) is not solved.